# enter selected checkbox values into database separated by commas

Tags: php

I have a php form with text boxes,radiobutton and checkboxes.I have written the coding for inserting the entered datas into database .my datas are getting entered except that of the checkbox values.i want to enter all the selected checkbox values within a single column separated by commas.can anyone correct my coding.I am not entering  the code here since half of the codings are getting hidden.please go to the folllowing link to view my coding.

http://pastebin.com/DTR9LvtZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
 $url = implode("," , $_REQUEST['url']);
```

to convert your array to a comma seperated string

Comment: thankyou but only one of the  selected checkbox values is getting entered.can you suggest any modification for entering all the selected values.

Comment: can u please tell me the place where I should insert it in my coding i have inserted it below the echo syntax